# I can't set a HTTP-Proxy on my wifi anymore

Tags: wifi, proxy

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I press save but still it isn't saved.. or being used?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to :

- Click on "Forget this network", search for this wifi, enter the password and try to set your proxy again
- Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network settings and try again

Comment: Was actually enough to just forget it and re-add it 